# Retrieving x-data from outside of an AlpineJS component

Tags: alpine.js

How do I retrieve a x-data data from an Alpine component outside of the component ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />    
    <title>AlpineJS Form Data</title>   
</head>
<body>
<form x-data="{ first_name: '', last_name: '' }" method="POST" @submit.prevent="submitForm($data)">
  <label>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" x-model="first_name">
  </label>
  <label>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" x-model="last_name">
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
let submitForm = (xData) =>
{
    console.log("xData = ", xData);
};
</script>
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.12.1/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />    
    <title>AlpineJS Form Data</title>   
</head>
<body>
<form x-data="{ first_name: '', last_name: '' }" method="POST" @submit.prevent="submitForm($data)">
  <label>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" x-model="first_name">
  </label>
  <label>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" x-model="last_name">
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
let submitForm = (xData) =>
{
    console.log("xData = ", xData);
};
</script>
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.12.1/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`$data` magic function](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/data) for this:

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>


<form x-data="{first_name: '', last_name: ''}" method="POST" @submit.prevent="submitForm($data)">
  <label>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" x-model="first_name">
  </label>
  <label>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" x-model="last_name">
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
let submitForm = ({first_name, last_name}) => {
    console.log("Name: ", first_name, last_name);
};

document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.store('user', {
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
    })
})
</script>
```